# Highlighting a new dom element using intro.js

Tags: javascript, html, intro.js

I'm using intro.js for the 'tour' for my web app. Since I'm trying to make this a quite user - interactive tour, I'm allowing the users to interact with the highlighted DOM elements on various steps.

There is a table with rows and columns in my app. Right-clicking a row shows a small 'options' div from which the user can choose to add a new row above/below the current row. When I begin the tour, I highlight the first row. Since I'm making this an interactive tour, I'm allowing the user to add a new row. My question is - how do I highlight the newly added row along with the selected row in the same step?  The series of steps should be something like this:-

STEP 1: (highlight something)

STEP 2:- Highlight a row. If user adds a new row (by right-clicking the current row and selecting 'Add a row above/below'), highlight the new row as well.

STEP 3:- (highlight something)

Comment: How about selecting the `tbody` instead of the row?

Comment: I can't select the tbody, since that highlights the entire table; effectively all rows get highlighted.

Comment: Then have you tried assigning some class to the rows, and using intro.js' JSON configuration --> http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/example/programmatic/index.html ?

Comment: @mef I tried it, but it adds an additional step. I want the user to be able to add a new row and then highlight the new row in the same step. Something like this:- STEP 1: <highlight something> STEP 2:- Highlight a row. If user adds a new row, highlight the new row as well. STEP 3:- <highlight something>

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/951ym964/2/

You have to call `introJs().refresh()` when rows are added.

Also, you have to use `tbody` to wrap the rows you want to highlight.

Comment: Went through the demo...I get the logic now..but the demo isn't highlighting the table row properly. It's completely white in color. And I face this exact same problem in my application too! :-(

Comment: it worked perfectly for me in firefox, so i tried it in Chrome and I see what you mean. It's a bug in intro.js, you can find a workaround here: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/146. Tip: next time you have a problem, reading the doc and github issues will save you time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the same `class` attribute value for all the rows
2. When a new row is added, rerun the row selection process based on the `class` value of the newly inserted row

Comment: Could you please elaborate further on this?